# How to use boolean to add numbers input by user?

Tags: java, boolean

I am writing this program for school work that asks the user to input a sequence of letters and numbers and determine whether it is a digit or not.

My teacher wants me to add up the characters that are digits(numbers) and output it as "Your numbers added up together are: *place added number here*"
and output the letters are a string saying "These are your letters: *place letters here."

I think I got the code right that determines whether it is a digit or not but how do I end up adding them? I tried using an if statement that checked if Character.isDigit is true but I keep getting errors and I think I'm writing it totally wrong. Any response would be greatly appreciated.

Here is my code:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class MyClass 
{
public static void main(String args[]) 
{

    int sum1 = 0;
    String stringFull = "";
    boolean isTrue = Character.isDigit(string1.charAt(i));




    Scanner getString = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter a sequence of letters: ");
    String string1 = getString.nextLine();

    for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        if (Character.isDigit(string1.charAt(i)))
        {
            sum1 += Character.getNumericValue(string1.charAt(i));

        } else {
            stringFull += string1.charAt(i);
        }

        if (isTrue)
        {
             System.out.println(sum1 * sum1);
        }

    }




}

}
```

Comment: *add up the characters that are digits* you mean sum ?

Comment: In Java you can't use variables that you haven't yet declared.  For instance, when you try `boolean isTrue = Character.isDigit(string1.charAt(i));`, `i` doesn't exist yet.

Answer (score 1):

You will get compilation error for below as `i` wasn't declared before this line

```
boolean isTrue = Character.isDigit(string1.charAt(i));
```

instead you should initialize it with `false`

```
boolean isTrue = false;
```

Then, your loop should loop till given string length, but you have hard-coded to 5, which will cause exception at runtime when string length is less than 5.

```
 for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
```

should change to

```
 for(int i = 0; i < string1.length(); i++)
```

Also, inside you `for` loop you are have following line of code, but you have never changed `isTrue` value inside the loop.

```
if (isTrue)
{
    System.out.println(sum1 * sum1);
}
```

And, I think, right place to change `isTrue` value, where you are checking for digit.

```
if (Character.isDigit(string1.charAt(i)))
{
    sum1 += Character.getNumericValue(string1.charAt(i));
    isTrue = true;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use

```
Integer.parseInt(String.valueOf(string1.charAt(i)))
```

which returns the number, instead of

```
Character.getNumericValue(string1.charAt(i))
```

which returns the ascii code for the number